# Dynamic styling in .Net Maui/Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, maui

Let's say I want to display a calendar. Each day (`DayViewModel`) can have such attributes that should influence styling:

- is day of current month
- is weekend
- is day available

And based on that I'd like to style my `DayContentView` like follows:

- if day of current month -> opacity 1
- if not current month -> opacity 0.5
- if weekend -> background color is red
- if available -> background color is green

Moreover the last one property ("is day available") can change based on user's action (clicked button "Check availability").

In other frameworks I'd create a few styles/style classes and assign them accordingly base on those flags. But since `StyleClass` is not bindable I cannot. Can I? Maybe there is some workaround.

Another option could be to create a separate style (using inheritance if needed) for all the combinations. But first of all the number of combinations raises like 2^n and the second issue is that I have no idea how to dynamically change whole styl for a view changing its name. Is it possible?

Finishing my quite long question: How to do it right/in a smart way? I don't want to store values of colors, font sizes, opacities etc. in a view model and bind all the values manually.

Comment: I understand what you are asking (but haven't thought of a solution), but others might not. Would help if you wrote "pseudo-code" that demonstrates what you *wish* you could do (but maybe can't). E.g. "if StyleClass was bindable I would write this xaml and/or c#". Show what that would look like (even though it won't compile).

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Good idea. I'll prepare something

Comment: Seems like [DataTemplateSelector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) might solve this easily

Comment: I'd created a ViewModel with all necessary attributes for styling. In your case it would be: IsDayOfCurrentMonth, IsWeekend, IsDayAvailable etc. After that you need to use MVVM binding model to link this properties to you View and use [Data Triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/triggers#data-triggers)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The same thing can be achieved using `DataTrigger`s.

Result:

[image: result]

MainPage.xaml

```xml
<Window
    x:Class="WpfApp6.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp6"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="800"
    Height="450"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <ItemsControl Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding Days}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:DayModel}">
                <Border
                    Padding="10"
                    Width="200"
                    Height="100"
                    Margin="5">
                    <Border.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="Border">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray" />
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsDayOfCurrentMonth}" Value="False">
                                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsAvailable}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsWeekend}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Border.Style>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding IsDayOfCurrentMonth, StringFormat='IsDayOfCurrentMonth: {0}'}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding IsAvailable, StringFormat='IsAvailable: {0}'}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding IsWeekend, StringFormat='IsWeekend: {0}'}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Window>
```

DayModel.cs

```cs
public record DayModel(bool IsDayOfCurrentMonth, bool IsWeekend, bool IsAvailable);
```

MainViewModel.cs

```cs
public class MainViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<DayModel> Days { get; } = new();

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        //Create all possible cominations of days
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++)
                {
                    Days.Add(new DayModel(i == 0, j == 0, k == 0));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT:** sharing style by multiple controls

Here's how the same `Style` with `Triggers` might be shared by multiple controls (two of the three `TextBlock`s in this example):

```xml
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:DayModel}">
    <Border
        Width="200"
        Height="100"
        Margin="5"
        Padding="10"
        Background="#eee">
        <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel.Resources>
                <Style x:Key="ColoredTextBlock" TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsDayOfCurrentMonth}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsAvailable}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsWeekend}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </StackPanel.Resources>
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ColoredTextBlock}" Text="{Binding IsDayOfCurrentMonth, StringFormat='IsDayOfCurrentMonth: {0}'}" />
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ColoredTextBlock}" Text="{Binding IsAvailable, StringFormat='IsAvailable: {0}'}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding IsWeekend, StringFormat='IsWeekend: {0}'}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

The result looks like this:
[image: sharing style example result]

Comment: This was extremely helpful. And it is working with my MVVM. I recommend it.

Comment: @Michal Diviš If I have a few labels that I'd like to style the same way then every laber needs to have the same `Style.Triggers` or am I missing something? For instance if I want to change `TextColor`

Comment: @user2146414 You don't have to copy the same `Style` for every label. The `Style` can be created within the `DataTemplate` (in `StackLayout.Resources` for example) and then shared for all the `Label`s.

Comment: @user2146414 I've updated the answer to include an example of sharing a style by multiple controls

Comment: @MichalDiviš Your solution is cool and I'm testing it (be prepared for bounty:)) But I have one more question: Let's say a day is both a weekend and a holiday. Weekend's background is gray. Holiday's background is red. The problem that I obseved is that the order of setting `IsWeekend` and `IsHoliday` matters because they both are `true`.  And that's not nice:/ How to address it? (I can create an example if more explanation needed)

Comment: I mean: I would like to define order declaratively via order of setters in XAML, not via the order of setting properties.

Comment: @user2146414 That depends on what you want to do with the background color in case both `IsWeekend` and `IsHoliday` are `true`. If you just want the weekend or holiday color to take over, that would depends on the order of the setters. The last setter wins. You could also add one more setter to the end, that would change to color to something else when both values are true. That could be done with a `MultiDataTrigger`.

Comment: @MichalDiviš Thanks a lot again. I didn't want mix things in this topic but maybe you know an answer to this my question:) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73755625/net-maui-styling-with-datatrigger

Answer (score 0):

I planned to add an example as @ToolmakerStave suggested but I found a solution in the meantime that seems to be very nice so I decided to share it instead. The idea is as follows:

1. Declare view model that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`
2. Create a XAML file and define there all the styles
3. In the code behind detect change of binding context (view model) and all its dynamically changing properties (`IsAvailable`) in my case
4. When a change is detected then create a style using styles defined in the XAML file applying them in the desired order (making updates)
5. Assign the final style to particular elements

So starting from my view model:

```
public class DayViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // To style
    public bool IsCurrentMonth { get; set; }
    public bool IsWeekend { get; set; }
    public bool IsHoliday { get; set; }
    
    private bool _isAvailable;
    public bool IsAvailable
    {
        get => _isAvailable;
        set
        {
            _isAvailable = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(
                this,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(IsAvailable))
            );
        }
    }

    // To display
    public string DayOfWeek { get; set; }
    public int DayOfMonth { get; set; }
}
```

Assuming that only `IsAvailable` property can change after some user action.

Then I have a XAML view that defines all the needed styles but they are not used directly in this file. I'll use them in the code behind. All the elements that I need to style have `x:Name` property set to get a reference to them from the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyProject.Calendar.ViewModels"
             x:Class="MyProject.Calendar.ContentViews.DayView"
             x:DataType="vm:DayViewModel">

    <ContentView.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <!-- By default Border has opacity 0.3 -->
            <Style TargetType="Border">
                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.3" />
            </Style>

            <!-- These styles are used from the code behind -->
            <Style x:Key="CurrentMonthBorder" TargetType="Border">
                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1.0" />
            </Style>
            <Style x:Key="WeekendBorder" TargetType="Border">
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="LightGray" />
            </Style>
            <Style x:Key="AvailableBorder" TargetType="Border">
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Green" />
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="HolidayLabel" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="DarkRed" />
            </Style>
            <!-- // These styles are used from the code behind -->
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentView.Resources>

    <Border x:Name="DayBorder">
        <VerticalStackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Label x:Name="DayOfWeekLabel" Text="{Binding DayOfWeek}" />
            <Label x:Name="DayOfMonthLabel" Text="{Binding DayOfMonth}"  />
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </Border>
</ContentView>
```

Now a helper class that allows to update a style with another style:

```
public static class StyleExtension
{
    public static Style Update(this Style style, Style otherStyle)
    {
        var result = new Style(style.TargetType);
        var allSetters = style.Setters.Concat(otherStyle.Setters);
        foreach (var setter in allSetters)
        {
            result.Setters.Add(setter);
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static Style UpdateIf(this Style style, bool condition, Style otherStyle)
    {
        return style.Update(condition ? otherStyle : new Style(style.TargetType));
    }
}
```

Final part, the code behind:

```
public partial class DayView : ContentView
{
    private DayViewModel _viewModel;

    public DayView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContextChanged += OnBindingContextChanged;
    }


    private void OnBindingContextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _viewModel = BindingContext as DayViewModel;
        _viewModel.PropertyChanged += OnAvailabilityChanged;   

        StyleDayBorder();
        StyleDayOfWeekLabel();
        StyleDayOfMonthLabel();
    }

    private void OnAvailabilityChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == nameof(DayViewModel.IsAvailable))
        {
            StyleDayBorder();
        }
    }

    private void StyleDayBorder()
    {
        DayBorder.Style = new Style(typeof(Border))
            .UpdateIf(_viewModel.IsCurrentMonth, GetStyle("CurrentMonthBorder"))
            .UpdateIf(_viewModel.IsWeekend, GetStyle("WeekendBorder"))
            .UpdateIf(_viewModel.IsAvailable, GetStyle("AvailableBorder"));
    }

    private void StyleDayOfWeekLabel()
    {
        DayOfWeekLabel.Style = new Style(typeof(Label))
            .UpdateIf(_viewModel.IsHoliday, GetStyle("HolidayLabel"));
    }

    private void StyleDayOfMonthLabel()
    {
        DayOfMonthLabel.Style = new Style(typeof(Label))
            .UpdateIf(_viewModel.IsHoliday, GetStyle("HolidayLabel"));
    }

    private Style GetStyle(string name)
    {
        return Resources[name] as Style;
    }
}
```

And final thought after the final code:) If there is no simpler solution then it would be nice to be able to do it in the XAML like this (pseudocode):

```
<Label Text="{Binding Message}">
    <Label.Styles>
        <Style ShouldApply="{Binding IsError}" Style="{StaticResource ErrorMessage}" />
        <Style ShouldApply="{Binding IsWarning}" Style="{StaticResource WarningMessage}" />
        ...
    </Label.Styles>
</Label>
```

And then all the styles would be created applying one after another in the defined order based on the defined conditions.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT Sure. Just need to wait some time because I have started a bounty. Maybe a better solution will appear:)

Comment: So why not DataTrigger?

Comment: @Shaw I think it is way to go. There are a few days left before the bounty finishes so I don't rush:)