# MAUI Android app working fine on emulator mode but crashes after publishing Apk

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, visual-studio-2022, maui

I am developing an android application using Visual Studio Community Edition 2022. When I run this application on an in-built pixel emulator / on a real device through a USB connection it works as expected. But after publishing and installing signed-apk on the same device or any other android mobile phone, the app crashes soon after the splash screen.

So far I tried following solutions I found over internet.

**Added following properties in my .csproj file**

```
<PublishTrimmed>False</PublishTrimmed>
<AndroidLinkMode>None</AndroidLinkMode>
<AndroidDexTool>d8</AndroidDexTool>

<PropertyGroup>
 <AndroidPackageFormat>apk</AndroidPackageFormat>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup>
 <AndroidEnableAssemblyCompression>false</AndroidEnableAssemblyCompression>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Still facing the same issue.

**MauiProgram.cs**

```
using CommunityToolkit.Maui;

namespace V2ROffline;

public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .UseMauiCommunityToolkit()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
            });
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<MainPage>();
        builder.Services.AddTransient<StockTakeWithoutFile>();
        return builder.Build();
    }
}
```

**App.xaml.cs**

```
namespace V2ROffline;

public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new AppShell();
    }
}
```

**App.xaml**

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8" ?>
<Application xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:V2ROffline"
             x:Class="V2ROffline.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Styles.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**AppShell.xaml.cs**

```
namespace V2ROffline;

public partial class AppShell : Shell
{
    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(StockTakeWithoutFile), typeof(StockTakeWithoutFile));
    }
}
```

**AppShell.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="V2ROffline.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:V2ROffline"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled">

    <ShellContent
        Title="Home"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
        Route="MainPage" />

</Shell>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
namespace V2ROffline;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using V2ROffline.lib;

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    int count = 0;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
/** Following code for checkWritePermission is not called
I believe app is crashing even before InitializeComponent() **/

        Task task = checkWritePermission();
        this.Title = Vars.TITLE + "-" + Vars.VERSION;
        TxtEmpCode.Focus();

    }
    private async Task checkWritePermission()
    {
        PermissionStatus status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.StorageWrite>();
        status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.StorageWrite>();
    }
    private void OnLoginClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string siteCode = TxtSiteCode.Text.Trim();
        string empCode = TxtEmpCode.Text.Trim();

        Regex regexSite = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}");
        Regex regexEmp = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z0-9]");

        if (!(empCode.Length >= 5 && empCode.Length <= 7 && regexEmp.IsMatch(empCode)))
        {
            DisplayAlert("Error", "Please enter valid Employee Code", "OK");
            TxtEmpCode.Focus();
            return;
        }

        if (!(siteCode.Length == 4 && regexSite.IsMatch(siteCode)))
        {
            DisplayAlert("Error", "Please enter valid Site Code", "OK");
            TxtSiteCode.Focus();
            return;
        }

        siteCode = siteCode.ToUpper();
        empCode = empCode.ToUpper();

        if (RbtnWithFile.IsChecked)
        {

        }
        else if (RbtnWithoutFile.IsChecked)
        {
            Task task = openStockTakeWithoutFile(empCode, siteCode);
        }
        else
        {
            DisplayAlert("Error", "Please select the mode of Stock Take", "OK");
            RbtnWithFile.Focus();
            return;
        }
    }

    async Task openStockTakeWithoutFile(string empCode, string siteCode)
    {
        var navigationParameter = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "EmpCode",  empCode},{ "SiteCode",  siteCode}
        };
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(StockTakeWithoutFile), navigationParameter);
    }

    private void OnExitClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        App.Current.Quit();
    }
}
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             x:Class="V2ROffline.MainPage">

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="InvalidEntryStyle" TargetType="Entry">
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Red" />
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="ValidEntryStyle" TargetType="Entry">
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Green" />
        </Style>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <Grid Margin="50,50" x:Name="GridList" VerticalOptions="Center">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions Padding="10,0">
            <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Employee Code" 
               FontAttributes="Bold"
               HeightRequest="20"
               HorizontalOptions="Start" />

        <Border Stroke="#505050"
        StrokeThickness="1"
        Background="#FFFFFF"
        Padding="10,0"
        Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
        HeightRequest="40"
        WidthRequest="170"
        HorizontalOptions="Start">
            <Border.StrokeShape>
                <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="5,5,5,5" />
            </Border.StrokeShape>
            <Entry x:Name="TxtEmpCode" 
               Placeholder="Enter employee code"
               TextTransform="Uppercase"
               MaxLength="7"
               >
                <Entry.Behaviors>
                    <toolkit:TextValidationBehavior 
                InvalidStyle="{StaticResource InvalidEntryStyle}"
                ValidStyle="{StaticResource ValidEntryStyle}"
                Flags="ValidateOnValueChanged"
                MinimumLength="5"
                MaximumLength="7" />
                </Entry.Behaviors>
            </Entry>
        </Border>
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Site Code"
               FontAttributes="Bold"
               HeightRequest="20"
               HorizontalOptions="Start" />
        <Border Stroke="#505050"
        StrokeThickness="1"
        Background="#FFFFFF"
        Padding="10,0"
        Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" 
        HeightRequest="40"
        WidthRequest="170"
        HorizontalOptions="Start">
            <Border.StrokeShape>
                <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="5,5,5,5" />
            </Border.StrokeShape>
            <Entry x:Name="TxtSiteCode" 
               Placeholder="Enter site code here"
               TextTransform="Uppercase"
               MaxLength="4"
               >
                <Entry.Behaviors>
                    <toolkit:TextValidationBehavior 
                InvalidStyle="{StaticResource InvalidEntryStyle}"
                ValidStyle="{StaticResource ValidEntryStyle}"
                Flags="ValidateOnValueChanged"
                MinimumLength="4"
                MaximumLength="4" />
                </Entry.Behaviors>
            </Entry>
        </Border>
        <RadioButton x:Name="RbtnWithFile" RadioButtonGroup.GroupName="StockTake" HeightRequest="30" Content="Stock take with file" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
        <RadioButton x:Name="RbtnWithoutFile" RadioButtonGroup.GroupName="StockTake" HeightRequest="30" Content="Stock take without file" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
        <Button Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0"
            x:Name="BtnExit"
            Margin="0,10,0,0"
            Text="Exit"
            WidthRequest="120"
            Clicked="OnExitClicked"
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
        <Button Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1"
            x:Name="BtnLogin"
            Margin="0,10,0,0"
            Text="Login"
            WidthRequest="120"
            Clicked="OnLoginClicked"
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </Grid>

</ContentPage>
```

Comment: What exception causes the crash?  Have you checked the logs or tried using any crash reporting tools?

Comment: @Jason please suggest any tool because the app works fine in debugging mode if I connect my device through a USB cable. The problem comes when I build an apk and install it on any device. So is there any app in the play store that I can install to check?

Comment: Use a tool like AppCenter or Raygun to get crash reports.  Or use adb to view log files from the device

Comment: @Jason one thing that I noticed on the android device. It suppose to have folder named `com.companyname.v2roffline` whereas I couldn't find such folder in `Android->data` folder. The same folder I can see when I run the app in `Debug` mode

Comment: The folder contains the data about your app and it will be created by the system when you install the app on the device. No matter Debug mode or Release mode, it will exist.

Comment: Yes exactly but that folder is not getting created on release mode. It is being created only on debug mode. That is why app is working fine on debug mode but crashes in release mode

Comment: Did you try to run it in the release mode on different devices?

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT Yes tried with 2 physical devices and 3 emulators of different android versions, but the problem is the same. In debug mode works absolutely fine but crashes in release mode.

Comment: If you create a new default project and run it in the release mode, will it crash?

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT Yes, the default project works fine in release mode. The problems comes after adding these lines `builder.Services.AddSingleton<MainPage>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<StockTakeWithoutFile>();` in `MauiProgram` and this line `Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(StockTakeWithoutFile), typeof(StockTakeWithoutFile));` in `AppShell`

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT is there anything to do with APK signing? Right now I don't have any value specified in `Apk signer additional arguments`. In android studio, I use v2 signer also.

Comment: You can try to use the break point to find which line cause the crash. In addition, you can try to download the android studio and check the device logcat when the app crashes.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT Break point doesn't work in release mode and I already switched back to Android Studio the app is working fine in Android Studio.

Comment: Sorry for my careless, do you mean when you run the app in the Android Studio and in the release mode, it worked well?

Comment: If so, you can check the project.csprojfile between the new project and this one.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT I usually use Android Studio for app development. I just wanted to try maui for its multiplatform thing so that I can have my all flavours under one project. But unfortunately couldn't make it work. Because I just added 2 screens only, I switched back to Android Studio and developed a new project there.in Java.

Comment: What does two screen mean? Two splash screen? The android splash screen in the maui is set in the share project.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT `MainPage` and `StockTakeWithoutFile` I am not counting the splash screen. By the way on release app crashes somewhere between Splash Screen and MainPage because app crashes after Splash Screen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248899/discussion-between-liyun-zhang-msft-and-maddy23285).

Comment: worried now, just ported an app from xamarin to maui, getting ready for release, if i can solve the pesky performance issue with scrolling that is. it runs faster in scrolling on the emulator than on my note 8+ and note 10+ ultra 5G 512GB physicals; oh - and it crashes when scrolling on the physical devices, but not in the emulator. suspect its  the loss of ffimagecaching that made it take the hit but difficult to know. 

any resolution on this question, noted the chat ended 15 days ago

Answer (score 2):

I am having the exact same problem.

-> **Release mode** working in both emulator and real devices.

-> After publishing and signing the app through VS 2022 publish option. We are not able to run the app on real devices **but** working as intended in **emulators**.

Comment: I have created a github issue about this. https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/11292

Answer (score 2):

As a developer for a small company (a little bit experienced with WPF) I decided to give a try to .NET MAUI while being asked for Android app development.

After several months of development, repetitively fighting with .NET MAUI issues I am hesitating to surrender. Unfortunately, it seems there is a lot of bugs in .NET MAUI leading to situation that development is more difficult than easy (although being promising something else). I recommended to read [this blog](https://pvs-studio.com/fr/blog/posts/csharp/0996/).

Today I finally found out that although my application was working in debug mode quite fine (workaround for the [styling issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75099469/14606023) had been found) switch to release mode leaded to quite different behavior (some triggers were not working, styling based on user entry not working at all).

I have just found [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74816988/net-maui-android-crashes-on-release-apk-with-android-runtime-javaproxythrowable) advising to focuse on Community Toolkit. It could have been the source of my issues with totally different styling as well...

I am going to update this answer with my final conclusion as soon as my investigation is done.