# .NET MAUI Android crashes on release apk with android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: System.InvalidOperationException: Android Activity can't be null

Tags: android, .net, maui

Not sure why its happening with so many resources being null but I cant seem to figure it out. I checked the mauiprogram.cs and it seems to be fine. It generates all the required resources for my app to run in debug mode.

```
Time    Device Name Type    PID Tag Message
12-15 13:53:50.503  pixel_5_-_api_33    Info    20162   MonoDroid   
android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: System.InvalidOperationException: Android Activity can't be null.
   at CommunityToolkit.Maui.Core.Platform.StatusBar.get_Activity()
   at CommunityToolkit.Maui.Core.Platform.StatusBar.PlatformSetColor(Color color)
   at CommunityToolkit.Maui.Core.Platform.StatusBar.SetColor(Color color)
   at CommunityToolkit.Maui.Behaviors.StatusBarBehavior.OnPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.BindableObject.SetValueActual(BindableProperty property, BindablePropertyContext context, Object value, Boolean currentlyApplying, SetValueFlags attributes, Boolean silent)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.BindableObject.SetValueCore(BindableProperty property, Object value, SetValueFlags attributes, SetValuePrivateFlags privateAttributes)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.BindableObject.SetValue(BindableProperty property, Object value, Boolean fromStyle, Boolean checkAccess)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.BindableObject.SetValue(BindableProperty property, Object value)
   at BlessingsApp.MainPage.InitializeComponent()
   at BlessingsApp.MainPage..ctor()
   at BlessingsApp.App..ctor()
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.InternalInvoke(Object , Object[] , Boolean )
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.DoInvoke(Object , BindingFlags , Binder , Object[] , CultureInfo )
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags , Binder , Object[] , CultureInfo )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite , RuntimeResolverContext )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[[Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[System.Object, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite , RuntimeResolverContext )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite , RuntimeResolverContext )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[[Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[System.Object, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite , RuntimeResolverContext )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.CreateServiceAccessor(Type )
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2[[System.Type, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Func`2[[Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[System.Object, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].GetOrAdd(Type , Func`2 )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type , ServiceProviderEngineScope )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type )
   at Microsoft.Maui.MauiContext.WrappedServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Maui.MauiContext.WrappedServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider , Type )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[IApplication](IServiceProvider )
   at Microsoft.Maui.MauiApplication.OnCreate()
   at Android.App.Application.n_OnCreate(IntPtr , IntPtr )
   at Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PP_V(_JniMarshal_PP_V , IntPtr , IntPtr )
    at crc6488302ad6e9e4df1a.MauiApplication.n_onCreate(Native Method)
    at crc6488302ad6e9e4df1a.MauiApplication.onCreate(MauiApplication.java:28)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1266)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6779)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleBindApplication(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2132)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7892)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
```

```
public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseSkiaSharp()
            .UseMauiApp<App>().UseMauiCommunityToolkit()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
            });
        builder.Services
                .AddScoped<IAuthenticationService, AuthenticationService>()
                .AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>()
                .AddScoped<IHttpService, HttpService>()
                .AddScoped<ILocalStorageService, LocalStorageService>();

        builder.Services.AddScoped(x => {
            var apiUrl = new Uri("http://localhost:5151/users/authenticate");


            return new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = apiUrl };
        });


        builder.Services.AddMauiBlazorWebView();
        #if DEBUG
        builder.Services.AddBlazorWebViewDeveloperTools();
#endif
        
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();


        return builder.Build();
    }
}
```

I tried changing some resources to see if it would change the error message but it didnt.

Comment: I have same problem  on debugging.. this was working find  did you find any solution for this

Comment: Just Marked the Answer :) see below. It was community toolkit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my issue, community toolkit status bar methods break when compiled with release on android.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Joe Next time write some more information please.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same Android Activity can't be null issue trying to set my Status Bar styles using .NET 6.0 and targeting CommunityToolkit.Maui 2.0.0.

I upgraded my Target SDK to .NET 7.0 and upgraded the Community.Toolkit.Maui to the latest stable version of 4.0.0.

Worked from there.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).