# How can I pass the value got by "Binding" to the "Value" property of DataTrigger in .NET MAUI 7?

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

How it looks like now: [Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyLSz.png).
I need to change **Label.TextColor** when the length of **Entry.Text** will be equal to **Entry.MaxLength**. I also have a MyEntry.cs file with MyEntry class.
Here is my code:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MyEntryTemplate">
    <Frame 
        Padding="7"
        CornerRadius="25"
        BorderColor="{TemplateBinding BorderColor}">
    <Frame.Resources>
        <controls:EntryTextConverter 
            Element="{Binding Source={x:Reference entry}}"
            x:Key="TextToIntConverter" />
    </Frame.Resources>
        <VerticalStackLayout>
            <Entry
                x:Name="entry"
                FontSize="{TemplateBinding EntryFontSize}" 
                Margin="2"
                MaxLength="{TemplateBinding EntryLength}" />
            <Label HorizontalOptions="End" >
                <Label.Text>
                    <Binding Source="{x:Reference entry}" Path="Text"
                             Converter="{StaticResource TextToIntConverter}" />
                </Label.Text>
                <Label.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger TargetType="{x:Type Label}"
                        Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference entry}, Path=Text.Length}"
                        Value="{TemplateBinding EntryLength}">
                        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Red"/>
                        <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Label.Triggers>
              </Label>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </Frame>
</ControlTemplate>
```

```
<controls:MyEntry
    Margin="20"
    EntryFontSize="25"
    BorderColor="Black"
    EntryLength="30" 
    ControlTemplate="{x:StaticResource MyEntryTemplate}"/>
```

Comment: use the same binding expression `"{TemplateBinding EntryLength}"` for both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You claim that you want this to be done with MVVM, yet you are doing all you can to break this architecture.

The truth is, that this Data Trigger:

```
<DataTrigger TargetType="{x:Type Label}"
      Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference entry}, Path=Text.Length}"
      Value="{Binding Source={x:Reference entry}, Path=MaxLength}" >
   <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Red"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

Does not have to know about the class Entry, that it has Property named "Text", and that property, has its own property "Length".

And you do not have to write random property names by hand, and making bugs in your program (because intelli-sense is not that intelligent all the time).

This Entry, should be bound to some property (yet I do not see that?!?).

And obviously you have already another property for MaxLenght (why is this variable, I do not know. It is not very common to have your MaxLength variable. Are you sure that this is what you want?).

So all you have to do is compare one string property length to another property. Nothing to do with Visual Elements here.

Edit: Take a look at this answer, you can learn more from here, than from the docs...
https://stackoverflow.com/a/73686153/6643940

Comment: This is the template of custom control element: some kind of _Entry with word counter_. That's why I need ***EntryLength*** property.
```<controls:MyEntry
    Margin="25"
    EntryLength="30"
    BorderColor="{StaticResource Yellow100Accent}"
    ControlTemplate="{StaticResource MyEntryTemplate}" />
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what solution you are suggesting. Could you please give an example. ***P.s***: I read the article you adviced

Comment: @luvairo Ok. What are you doing with this entry? You enter something right? What are you doing with this? Where is your entered text binding?

Comment: Look, I edited the question

Comment: @luvairo I am asking again. What are you doing with this Entry. Where is your Entry Text bound to a string Property? None of the code you posted, even hints that this is used for something.

Comment: It's just a template of my control (I am just training). I don't have backend code in ViewModel for this. Do you want to see MyEntry.cs file? Sorry for my misunderstanding)

Comment: @luvairo the moment you try to use it for something, you will understand what I mean. Try to use it, so you see the need of templated binding to the text. And then you will see that you can use the very same property (more specifically, its length) , to determine that it has reached MaxLength.

Comment: Alright, I'll try it. I still have an another problem: when launching the application, the maximum length indicator shows the int.MaxValue value, although I explicitly set another one. Moreover, when you enter the first character in the Entry, the indicator changes the value to the correct one. (Look at the .png file I attached). It feels like the converter is triggered before the "EntryLength" property gets the value (therefore, int.MaxValue is set from my definition of BindableProperty)

Comment: @luvairo And you will keep having problems. Do not bind to visual element properties.

Comment: You mean, I have to add some properties to MyEntry.cs file instead of binding to visual element properties? Should I use DataTrigger at all?

Comment: Could you please give an example of "Good programming style" in my situation. It will be helpful for me

Comment: @luvairo Yes, I advise you to do so. Then you can cheat this non-refreshing, by invoking OnPropertyChanged here and there. And yes, DataTrigger is indeed one of the ways to have your UI respond to your data. It is decent choice for what you are trying to do.

Comment: @luvairo this what you are doing, is quite good. I do not see your MyEntry.cs, but I can see that it already contains bindable properties, and you have used TemplateBinding to get to it.  You can then bind it to your ViewModel, and make shananigans like setting it to 0 , before setting it to 30, so you trigger OnPropertyChanged. (and other tricks).

Comment: Thanks for your answers) I have one last question left: how can complex animation be implemented? For example, how to make an animation similar to a standard button (where waves propagate from the point of pressing)

Comment: Is it Custom button class of smth?

Comment: @luvairo you should really open new question for this. When we discuss this in comments, other people do not take part. I have general knowledge about animations. There are far more competent people, that will be of much better use, than me.